# error while connecting my mongo db using prisma

Tags: mongodb, database-connection, prisma

after creating schema i hit npx prisma generate then i hit npx prisma db push then it is giving me following error plsss help...
The provided database string is invalid. An invalid argument was provided: Database must be defined in the connection string in database URL. Please refer to the documentation in https://www.prisma.io/docs/reference/database-reference/connection-urls for constructing a correct connection string. In some cases, certain characters must be escaped. Please check the string for any illegal characters.

i was trying to push in my mongodb

following is my mongodb url
mongodb+srv://pramitinps:Pramit@cluster0.cx1apmz.mongodb.net/?retryWrites=true&w=majority